# Including file in php

Tags: php

I am a jsp programmer who has taken up a little homework to learn php on my own ;)
So my question is on including files in php document.
To Explain here is the code.

**index.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("/php/lib/banner.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

**banner.php**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="../../images/banner.jpg" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

**file locations :**

```
main\index.php  
main\php\lib\banner.php  
main\images\banner.jpg
```

The error I get is that no image is displayed in Index page, but it works when I directly access banner.php

Please suggest.

Regards
Sworoop Mahapatra

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include literally puts the contents of one file into the other, so you want the path to be the path you would use in index.php (images/banner.jpg)

Comment: Thank you. but what i need is that i have to include the same file in other documents also. so am sure putting the images in the root of every document to work will be a waste.

in jsp the same method works.

Answer (score 1):

When you are including a php file using the include function, the parser actually grabs the content from 'banner.php' and inserts in the place where it has been called.

Now the image source though you referred with respect to the directory of banner.php, when `include` is used it should be referred with correct pointer with respect to the directory of index.php (The directory of the file where it as been called)

In your case it is requesting the image from two directories **UP** the main directory where the image does not exist !!

To work use :

`<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" />`

Comment: Yes i figured that part. will go for keeping images in all the root then..

thanks all for the reply.

but can someone please tell me that why this method works in jsp page but not in php?

Comment: Its not a good habit to put images in root directory. Instead you could put all images in some folder say "images" and then include an additional script in every php file which determines the path of that particular php file in the server using "pathinfo" function 
[ref : http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php ]

Determine its directory and then based on it adjust the image path
/images if the php is present in root ../images if present in one directory down the root directory
***Too Complex*** isn't it ??

I'm new to JSP currently..as u are learning php, so am I learning jsp

Answer (score 0):

```
This should work:

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Banner</title>
</head>
<body>
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. but what i need is that i have to include the same file in other documents also. so am sure putting the images in the root of every document to work will be a waste.

in jsp the same method works.

Comment: You can use css for images then it will work

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.. will try that and get back to you in the evening.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you load the index.php the banner.php location is starting from...

`main\`

When you load the banner.php alone the location is...

`main\php\lib\`

You can't really have one URL that will work on both. Do you need to load the banner separately? If you only need the banner to work in your index.php then change the line to...

`<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" /></td>`

and it will work from index.php, but not when you load up banner.php.

To get it working on both, you will need to copy them to the same folder or at least modify the structure of your folders a bit.

EDIT: If you can tell me the location of the other files that this banner needs to be on, just list and I'll try see how it can be sorted.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
what i need is that the file banner.php will be included in many php documents.
such as index.php,temples.php,hotels.php all in separate folders
so I have to keep the images in all the root folders of the documents?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, but all the `include("/php/lib/banner.php");` is doing is putting the code from banner.php into your index.php. Your  folder according to the file will be `main\`

List some other file locations that it will need to work on and I'll try sort it for you.

Comment: rite now the current format is 
main-> index.php  
main->php->x.php  
main->php->hotels->mayfair.php etc

Comment: Ok.. the simplest way to fix it is obviously put something like `<img src="http://www.website.com/images/banner.jpg" width="100%" />`. That way it'll work from anywhere.

Comment: main\index.php  
main\php\hotels\mayfair.php
main\php\hotels\mayfair\details.php
main\php\packages\1-2nite.php
main\php\packages\1-2nite\details.php

Comment: ok... u mean like imageshack?
or like my own website?
absolute instead of relative

Comment: Another easy way to do it would be to just simply put banner.jpg in the same folder at banner.php

Comment: www.website.com is your own website. I put that there because I don't know what it is. I mean... If you put that kind of link it doesn't matter where banner.php is loaded from.. it will not get confused with folder locations but rather load it from `http://www.website.com/images/banner.jpg` every time.

Comment: i got that.. will get back to you if not solved by evening :)

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just leave the code inside the body element in the banner.php file. PHP will take the content of the file literally and insert it where the include function is at. In the current form of the code, you will en up with an html element inside the body element of your page, which is totally wrong and might result in unexpected behavior for the browser.

Also, the path must be relative to URL you are actually visiting in the browser, not relative to the file the HTML code comes from.

A layout like this will work:

index.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php include("php/lib/banner.php"); ?>
</body>
</html>
```

banner.php

```
<table width="100%">
<tr>
<td>
<img src="images/banner.jpg" width="100%" /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

same file locations :

```
main\index.php  
main\php\lib\banner.php  
main\images\banner.jpg
```

Just keep in mind that an include will take a PHP file, proccess it and include its result literally.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution is to have the complete path to image.

For example:

```
<img src="http://yoururl/image_path"/>
```